# Start dialer process in dotnetcf 2.0 (WM6)

Tags: c#, windows, compact-framework, windows-mobile-6

I want to bring up the phone dialer from my application. The app is developed in dot net compact framework 2.0 and targeted to run on Windows Mobile 6 devices.
I do not want to initiate and handle calls from inside my application. I just want to bring up the native phone dialer on a key press.
For example, when I want to bring up browser, I do following:
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("iexplore.exe", "http://www.stackoverflow.com");

Any help will be appreciated.

Regards

Sarwar Erfan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
using Microsoft.WindowsMobile.Telephony;
```

and

```
Phone phone = new Phone();
phone.talk(null, true);
```

or

```
phone.talk("", true);
```